# Asymptotic behavior of exp(H_n)

Tags: asymptotics

I have next problem:
$$ e^{H_n} = ... + O(\frac1n)$$

$H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k $

I have got the following result:

From ($ H_n > \ln n + \gamma $) I go to $e^{H_n} \geq n e^{\gamma}$

Therefore $e^{H_n} = n e^{\gamma} + ... + O(\frac1n)$

What is the next step to get remaining elements of the sum?

Comment: hmmm why not just put in more terms of the asymptotic expansion of $H_n$

Comment: You need a more exact approximation for $H_n$ if you want to determine $e^{H_n}$ to the $O(1/n)$ term. Do you know a more exact approximation?

Comment: WolframAlpha says that next element is  $\frac{e^{\gamma}}{2}$. But I don't understand how to get this result.

Comment: Yes, I know $H_n = \ln n + \gamma + \frac1{2n} + O(\frac{1}{n^2})$

Comment: I am not sure it is correctly write following:

$ e^{H_n} = n e^{\gamma + \frac{1}{2n}} e^{O(\frac{1}{n^2})} = n e^{\gamma + \frac{1}{2n}} (1 + O(\frac{1}{n^2}))$

Comment: That is correct, but it's in my opinion better to write $$e^{H_n} = n e^{\gamma} \exp \biggl(\frac{1}{2n} + O(n^{-2})\biggr)$$ and then expand $\exp \bigl(\frac{1}{2n} + O(n^{-2})\bigr) = 1 + \frac{1}{2n} + O(n^{-2})$.